# Return Value based on Key in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm quite new to the world of JS and Node so this might seem like quite an easy thing to do, but it's something I just can't seem to get working.

Say I have the following json example in a json file

```
{
"0": "somestring1",
"1": "somestring2",
"2": "somestring3",
"3": "somestring4",
"4": "somestring5",
"5": "somestring6",
"6": "somestring7"
}
```

and in my server.js file I am loading the file like so

```
var fs = require('fs')

var parsedJson = fs.readFile('./jsonfile.json', function (err, data) 
{
  res.write(data);
  res.end();
})
```

hitting the server returns all of the json (as expected) but what I want to do is parse the file and return a single value based on a key, so something along the lines of:

```
for (var entry in data)
{
    if (entry.key == 0)
    {
      res.write(thing.value);
      //"somestring1" would be sent here
    }
}
```

How is this sort of thing done in JS/Node. Everything I have tried doesn't seem to work

Thanks!

Kris

Comment: `var parsed = JSON.parse(data); res.write(parsed[0]);`

Comment: @AndyRay YUNO submit as answer?

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was going to be something really easy, Post as answer and I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data.json'));

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var key = req.url.replace('/', '');
  var value = data[key];

  if (value) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end(value);
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Not Found');
  }
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Then on the command line:

```
$ curl localhost:1337/1
somestring2

$ curl localhost:1337/x
Not Found
```